How can I redirect the output of my pool filter's backwash waste water?
I desire to backwash my pool filter, but I do not wish to "just dump" the waste water onto the ground next to the pool equipment. Instead I would like to redirect the waste water approximately 20 feet laterally (and slightly downhill) to a nearby yard drain.
The filter model is a "Jandy DEL 60 CP". It appears to be equipped with an external "2-in-1 Backwash Valve" (looks similar to this). The backwash output of this valve is extended by a short run of pipe which terminates in what appears to be a simple ball valve (see attached photo.) I have inspected the open end of this valve piece and it is without threads and measures roughly 2 7/16ths inches ID and 2 15/16th inches OD.
My question in parts is:

What variety/diameter of hose would be appropriate to redirect the waste water from this backwash valve
...and how can I temporarily and securely connect it to the open end of the valve at the end of the backwash waste pipe

EDIT: Added emphasis to the word "temporarily" as I do not wish to permanently attach anything to this valve. I just need a way to redirect the water for a few minutes a few times a year. I was thinking to use some sort of hose material instead of rigid PVC pipe so that when not in use I can coil up the hose and store it.


...and how should I filter/process the final output before it enters the nearby yard drain?

EDIT: My concern with filtering is both larger debris (such as leaves and small stones) and also filter media (diatomaceous earth.)





check if you are allowed to discharge that in the storm drain, last time I checked pool waste had to go with grey water,

You need to make a trip to the local pool store or check to see if the big box stores have a 2 inch backwash hose.  You need a short piece of 2 inch PVC pipe and PVC glue also.
Glue the 2 inch pipe to the ball valve.  When the glue is dry you can attach the hose with the clamp and direct it to where you want it to discharge.
At the discharge area lay the end of the hose on a couple of washable or disposable AC filters. These can be purchased in bulk on a roll to make the cost lower.  However you should be able to use one multiple times.
The hose obviously rolls into a compact package.
Having the water flow over the mat/s does the filtering of larger debris that you want.

That appears to be a standard PVC ball valve. Take a trip to a plumbing supply house or a big-box store, and grab a couple different PVC fittings and pieces of pipe that measure as reasonably close as possible to the internal size of the open valve end. Use a tape measure or internal/external caliper to match the diameters.
When you get back home, find the fitting or pipe that press-fits reasonably firmly into that ball valve end. That's the one whose pipe size you should use to come out of the ball valve.
Attach a small piece of the correct size PVC pipe to the ball valve, using standard PVC primer and glue. Then attach a PVC union:

source
of the same size pipe to allow removing the drain hose from the ball valve. The other end of the PVC union can be attached to a length of rubber hose, through a hose barb fitting. Hose sizes of the same size as the ball valve's PVC pipe are available, but may be a bit expensive. You may want smooth-inside pipe instead of corrugated pipe, so the stuff that needs filtering won't catch and clog in the pipe. Fittings exist to go from pipe to the hose, and hose clamps can make the hose grab the hose fitting well. The PVC union has its own spinning lock nut, so the whole hose won't have to turn to remove the hose from the ball valve.
At the end of the hose near the yard drain, you can get a mesh laundry bag with mesh size less than the chunks & stuff that will come out of the backwash. A large enough bag can catch all the junk, or you might have to swap out bags. Attach another hose barb fitting to the yard drain end of the hose, so the hose will have a lip, and the bag won't slide off the end of the hose when the water runs.

I edited my question to highlight the desire for a temporarily installation. Certainly rigid PVC would do the job, but there is nowhere good to run it. I am looking for a temporary solution that I can install only when it is needed.
On another note: Thank you for highlighting the filtering requirement. My thinking with the third part of my question "...and how should I filter/process the final output before it enters the nearby yard drain?" was to determine if there is some sort of filter bag I could attach to the end of my redirected waste water hose.

OK, tweaked for a temporary, removable solution, and a filter system at the end of the hose.

That PVC ball valve is meant to be glued to something. If you want a detachable piece, you should permanently add an adapter.
My pool was threaded already with 1.5" NTP, so I added this Camlock adapter, and then snap this hose on when I need to do a  backwash.
Your ball valve is 2" PVC, so you could glue on this PVC adapter, thread in this Camlock adapter, and then only connect this hose when you need to backwash.

